# txtRecord is null when browsing for services (bonjour) using MYNetwork libraries

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, networking, bonjour

I am currently working with [MYNetwork](https://bitbucket.org/snej/mynetwork/wiki/Home) library Bonjour classes and have a problem discovering txt records. When a new service appears it's txt record is null every time.

On my server side I setup txt record this way:

```
self.server = [[MYBonjourRegistration alloc] initWithServiceType: @"_blipecho._tcp." port:9121];
[server setString:@"Cyprian" forTXTKey:@"Name"];
[server start];
```

Then on the Browser I discover and log the data:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
    {
        if ([keyPath isEqual:@"services"]) {

            NSSet *newServices = (NSSet*)[change objectForKey:@"new"];

            if(newServices){

                MYBonjourService *service;
                for (service in newServices){
                    textView.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nNew user: %@ (%@)", textView.text, service.name, [service txtRecord]];

                }
            }
    }
```

And I get null for the txtRecord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got the answer.

The problem was that the newly discovered service is was no yet resolved hence there was no data.

Had to resolve the service first.

```
-(void)resolveService:(MYBonjourService*)service{

    service.addressLookup.continuous = YES;
    [service.addressLookup addObserver: self
                            forKeyPath: @"addresses"
                               options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                               context: NULL];
    [service queryForRecord: kDNSServiceType_NULL];
}
```